# Altering the contents of a Collection outside the scope of an instance method?

Tags: java, collections

Is it best practices to never alter the contents of a `Collection` that is passed as a parameter?

I want `orgSet` to only have words. But, sometimes there are one char strings (like question marks, commas, etc.) that I want to remove from the set of words. These are not the full methods, but it makes my point:

```
 public static Set<String> removeSyntax_Foo(Set<String> orgSet) {
        Set<String> tmpSet = new HashSet();  
        for(String s : orgSet) {
            if(s.length()!=1) { tmpSet.add(s); }
            if(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(s.charAt(0)) == Character.UnicodeBlock.GENERAL_PUNCTUATION) { continue; }
            tmpSet.add(s);
        }
        return tmpSet;
    }

    public static void removeSyntax_Bar(Set<String> orgSet) {
        Set<String> tmpSet = new HashSet();
        tmpSet.addAll(orgSet);
        orgSet.clear();

        for(String s : tmpSet) {
            if(s.length()!=1) { orgSet.add(s); }
            if(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(s.charAt(0)) == Character.UnicodeBlock.GENERAL_PUNCTUATION) { continue; }   
            orgSet.add(s);
        }
    }
```

`removeSyntax_Foo()` has the potential for a careless memory leak. I actually have a list of static methods I use to *clean-up* my `Set` of words. If each of those methods creates a new collection... But, I feel this is the correct solution to use.
`removeSyntax_Bar()` jumbles the contents of the invoker's `Set` which might be a huge surprise to the invoker. You are not suppose to do that, right?

Is `removeSyntax_Foo()` or `removeSyntax_Bar()` best practices?

Comment: I disagree that this is primarily opinion-based: there are well-established and objective criteria for answering this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_Foo()` variant, treating the input as read-only, is more thread-safe.  For example, a parallel thread could do something else with `origSet` (again, in a read-only manner) while your code is trimming punctuation.  The `_Foo()` variant will cause fewer surprises and probably less bugs.  And, it is more flexible for future requirements.  For example, somebody adds a requirement to create a set of the punctuation.  Possible with the `_Bar()` version, but much easier with`_Foo()`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is mostly six of one, half a dozen of the other.
For my simple need of cleansing html mark-up, numbers, syntax, etc. out of a tokenized doc, `removeSyntax_bar()` makes sense; those are simple utility methods. But, for interface design intended for public consumption, `removeSyntax_foo()` is what you're suppose to do.